# Items of Listview do not appear as a real list in android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a simple class `MainActivity` which extends `ListActivity` and inside it I created an `ArrayList` using  `ArrayAdapter`.

Then in the xml file  I added a background to my application. When I run the application the items defined in the `MainActivity` do not appear as a single list of items. Actually they appear in separate pages. I mean each item is defined in a new page. And this is caused only because I added the background.

`MainActivity` class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         ArrayList<String> raid_list = new ArrayList<String>();
         raid_list.add("Android");
         raid_list.add("iPhone");

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.label, raid_list);
         setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And the xml file goes like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mybackground" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@+id/label_text"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix this misbehavior?  Thanks.

Comment: extends with normal Activity and remove the orientation in xml file.and remove the android:text="@+id/label_text" in textview. tru this may help you.

Comment: This will not work as `ListActivity` must be extended in order to use the functions I used

Comment: can you explain what you mean by items coming in different pages

Comment: Ok I will post an image.

Comment: try this tutorial :http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ListActivity with custom layout file then you need to add ListView into this layout with android:id="@android:id/list"

Answer (score 0):

Some important mistakes:

First: you need to create a layout to define how is going to look this screen. Something like this (It is going to be called "activity_list_view_android_example.xml"):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

NOTE :
When creating Listview with ListActivity then two things are MUST contain a ListView with the android:id attribute set to @android:id/list ( NOT android:id="@+id/list" ).
if you will defined ListView with the android:id attribute set to @+id/list then it will give error.

After you will need to inflate this xml file like your screen layout:

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);
```

Second error: in the xml that you define for each row of the list  (in your code is called activity_main.xml) you have to define your row, not how the full list activity is going to look. So, you can't to have each row with the max hight of the screen, right? Fix it please:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:background="@drawable/mybackground" >
```

Comment: If it is helping you, could you please rating my answer and set up as a valid response, please? Thanks

Comment: You are saying that, I should have two different xml file? I didn't understand it

Comment: Yes, you need to have 2 different xml files: one for define the look of your screen and other one to define how is going to look each row of your listiview.

Comment: The one that you use in this line of code (ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.label, raid_list);)  activity_main.xml --> it is going to define how look each individual row of your listivew

Comment: I recommend you to change this layout name from activity_main to list_row_item.xml or something like that.

Comment: But you are saying to do `setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);`. What about the `activity_main.xml`? Wher should I inflate it?

Comment: My head is confused. Could you please edit your post by defining the correct definitions and their codes?

Comment: In setContentView you have to inflate how look the full screen where you need to define one element <LisView> with the name "@android:id/list"..........activity_main.xml in your case is going to define how look the row...you don't need inflate it! The adapter will do for you.

Comment: Think a little bit about it, please. http://androidexample.com/Create_Listview_With_ListActivity_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=66&aaid=91

Comment: My dear friend I  can do it if there would no background image. So I am asking for that case.

Comment: I don't understand you what do you want exactly

Comment: The picture you sent to me from the link contains a list. That's ok. Now I want that list to be displayed inside my background. Do you get it?